# Creating an image view by pixels

Tags: ios, uiimageview, bmp

I want to create an iOS app that contains a uiimageview and a button so that when a user hits a button the image view is generated by a set of 2 nested while loops that set the pixels for the uiimageview. i can do this in C with a bitmap quite easily but I'm not sure how to approach this for iOS could I save a bitmap to NSUserDefaults and load it from there?
Not sure, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageView` works with `UIImage`, which is a `UIKit`'s wrapper for `CGImage`. In any case you should have either a `CGImage` or `UIImage`. What can you do? Draw an image dynamically using CoreGraphics and/or UIKit's drawing methods (take a look at [Quartz2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)). Or if you can have a raw byte data of your image you can directly create an `UIImage` instance:

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void*)myByteArray length:sizeof(myByteArray)];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

then just set your `UIImageView`'s `image` property:

```
self.myImageView.image = img;
```